# "Transform" terminal command in AppleScript

Tags: terminal, finder, applescript

I created this terminal command and it works perfectly. Now I would like to finish it...

```
find /Users/xxxxx/Downloads/PDF -iname "*.pdf" |tr "\n" "\0" |xargs -0 /Users/xxxxx/Downloads/cpdf-binaries-master/OSX-Intel/cpdf -o /Users/xxxxx/Downloads/PDF/merged.pdf
```

Now the question...when executing the command I would like the finder window to appear for "where to search" and at the end a finder window for "where to save". It's possible? How could I solve?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to ask for folders in AppleScript, here's an example:

```
set theInputFolder to choose folder with prompt "Please select input folder:"
set theInputFolderPOSIX to POSIX path of theInputFolder -- POSIX path that is used in shell scripts
set quotedInputFolder to quoted form of theInputFolderPOSIX -- quoted form to handle spaces in path

set theOutputFolder to choose folder with prompt "Please select output folder:"
set theOutputFolderPOSIX to POSIX path of theOutputFolder -- POSIX path that is used in shell scripts
set quotedOutputFolder to quoted form of theOutputFolderPOSIX -- quoted form to handle spaces in path

set theResponse to display dialog "Output filename" default answer "merged" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue"

do shell script "find " & quotedInputFolder & " -iname '*.pdf' |tr '\n' '\\0' |xargs -0 /Users/xxxxx/Downloads/cpdf-binaries-master/OSX-Intel/cpdf -o " & quotedOutputFolder & "/"  & (text returned of theResponse) & ".pdf"
```

Note: It's safer to use quoted forms, because of possible spaces in the folder path.

Comment: OK thanks. How can I integrate this script with mine? Also, you talk about the input folder, but for "where to save". I don't know if it's clear what I need, sorry ...

Comment: @Axelv73 OK, I've made the whole script.

Comment: Mmmmmm...Applescript give me error: Syntax error. Expected "" "but unknown token was found.

Comment: There is a problem in the last line and I don't understand what ...

Comment: Double escape `\0` sorry about that. Fixed

Comment: Another error..."Script error:  /users/xxxxx/Downloads/OUTPUT/ is a directory. Maybe the create output file command is missing?

Comment: Sorry, the script was missing `merged.pdf` at the end.

Comment: Thanks Mateusz, I will try as soon as possible! Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks Mateusz! It works great! A curiosity .... if I also wanted to give a name to the file once the choice of the output folder appears?

Comment: @Axelv73 I've added prompt for output filename.